# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity lost when I perform a call to WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, silverlight

First at all thanks to all for sharing all the knowledge with the community.

I currently have a Silverlight application that consumes some WCF services. These WCF services use a custom authorization policy which expect an Identity with roles to authorize or not.

In this application all is working fine. I create a channel with the WCF and the Identity is passed from the client to the server.

The problems come when I tried to consume those WCF services from another ASP Net MVC application. I have tried to replicate the `web.config` in this new application, to maintain the configuration and try to make it easier.

In this new application when I look in the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` variable in my `IAuthorizationPolicy` class, it is empty and the authorization fails.

So the next test that I did  was host the WCF in this new application, to avoid authentication between sites. I perform a `FormsAuthentication` in the site and I create a cookie to store the user information, when I navigate between pages the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` has value in my `HttpModule` class, but when I call to the WCF service this HTTModule class  has not value in the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` variable.

I am stuck because I do not understand this behavior.

If in my `HttpModule` class always return a new fixed `GenericIdentity`, it works fine when I consume the WCF services hosted in the own application.

If I consume the services hosted in the original application it does not work although I return the new `GenericIdentity` in the `HttpModule`.

I've spent some days with this issue so I need your kindly assistance. I read a lot about WCF architecture but I need a clue from someone.

Thanks in advance.